# A faster way to do these dataframe operations?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I am loading a dataframe from csv, and then performing the operations below. Loading the dataframe takes about 2 seconds. The other operations ( mainly the date conversions ) take 30 seconds. Is there a way to speed up the other operations?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( fn, index_col=None )

df['SCHEDULED_OFF'] = pd.to_datetime( df['SCHEDULED_OFF'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M' )
df['LATEST_TAKEN'] = pd.to_datetime( df['LATEST_TAKEN'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' )
df['FIRST_TAKEN'] = pd.to_datetime( df['FIRST_TAKEN'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' )
df['SETTLED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime( df['SETTLED_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' )
df['ACTUAL_OFF'] = pd.to_datetime( df['ACTUAL_OFF'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' )
df['ACTUAL_OFF'] = df['ACTUAL_OFF'].fillna( pd.datetime.min )
df[ 'LATEST_TAKEN_FROM_SCHEDULED_OFF' ] = ( df['SCHEDULED_OFF'].values -df['LATEST_TAKEN'].values ) / np.timedelta64( 1, 's' )
df[ 'FIRST_TAKEN_FROM_SCHEDULED_OFF' ] = ( df['SCHEDULED_OFF'].values -df['FIRST_TAKEN'].values ) / np.timedelta64( 1, 's' )
df[ 'IN_PLAY' ] = [ dicInPlay[ x ] for x in df[ 'IN_PLAY' ] ]
df['COUNTRY'] = df['COUNTRY'].fillna( '' )
df['FULL_DESCRIPTION'] = df['FULL_DESCRIPTION'].fillna( '' )
df['EVENT'] = df['EVENT'].fillna( '' )
df['COURSE'] = df['COURSE'].fillna( '' )
```

Comment: Have you tried telling the csv parser which columns are date columns and then creating the df like this? `df = pd.read_csv( csv_path, parse_dates=['SCHEDULED_OFF','LATEST_TAKEN','FIRST_TAKEN','SETTLED_DATE','ACTUAL_OFF'])` I think should work

Comment: I just knocked up a dummy csv and it handles all your varying date formats without issue so try my suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but it seems a lot slower than the original method.;{

Comment: What is slower, you claimed the date conversion routines were the slowest part, by telling the csv parser upfront which columns are dates in order to parse them this should've been quicker

Comment: @EdChum This is not necessarily slower: the `parse_dates` feature in `read_csv` just uses `to_datetime` under the hood in many cases. The speed will depend on the date format. And in this case, a `dayfirst=True` would be needed, which is a lot slower than providing the format in `to_datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution, but a way to do this faster is having the dates in standard ISO format ...

To illustrate this can make a big difference, some timings (with a column of 10000 date strings):

```
# with standard ISO formatted strings (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)
In [52]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop

# with your dayfirst-like format (%d-%m-%Y %H:%M)
In [66]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
10 loops, best of 3: 78.2 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 800 ms per loop
```

So I think part of the reason it is slow, is this date parsing (20-30 time slowdown when not having standard ISO format). And I don't know if this can be further enhanced if you can't change the format.

For the other lines I don't directly see a possible spead-up, only for `[ dicInPlay[ x ] for x in df[ 'IN_PLAY' ] ]` you could test if `df['IN_PLAY'].map(dicInPlay)` is faster.